# Dos command in c# - RedirectStandardError/Output problem

Tags: c#, .net

I need to run Dos commands within a class.  My problem is that the redirect options seem to prevent the command from running.
Here is my code:

```
public static int executeCommand(string cmd)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C " + cmd);
        int exitCode = 0;
        //processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        //processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process =
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);

        process.WaitForExit(); //wait for 20 sec
        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        //string stdout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        //string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.Close();
        return exitCode;
    }
```

When I call xcopy:

```
if (executeCommand("xcopy.exe " + "/E /I /R /Y /Q c:\\temp\\*.* e:\\temp\\b1\\ ") != 0)
                Log.Error("Error detected running xcopy ");
```

The method correctly runs xcopy.  If I want to redirect the SDTOUT and STDERR, the method returns 0 as well but xcopy didn't really run.

In other words, this doesn't work:

```
public static int executeCommand(string cmd)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", "/C " + cmd);
        int exitCode = 0;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process =
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);

        process.WaitForExit(); //wait for 20 sec
        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        string stdout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        process.Close();
        return exitCode;
    }
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quirk of xcopy.exe, you must redirect stdin as well.  Check [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/8d60e975-eb0a-487a-878b-719c984a6e97) for my original diagnostic.  No need to use cmd.exe btw, just call xcopy directly.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you.  The code above as well and my code both work now.  I did noticed that other commands were executed correctly.  Just xcopy was not working.
Thanks
Tony